# Прикладное программирование vs web-программирование

Tags: c#, работа

На данный момент очень популярна разработка web-приложений (+ всякие решения для sharepoint и прочее). Наверное, начинать лучше именно в этой области (если интересует именно зарплата и перспектива её роста).

Собственно, вопрос: прикладное программирование вымирает? Что делать, если web-разработка дико неинтересна (не важно по какой причине, вот не нравится и всё), а хочется работать, например, над интересными проектами и получать адекватную зарплату в то же время (если сравнивать, можно получать n денег за разработку под sharepoint при опыте в m лет и n/2 при том же опыте, но при разработке, например, Win-приложения)?

**upd:** вопрос состоит в том, реально ли сейчас найти работу не web и в то же время с адекватной зарплатой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще как реально! Нужно знать куда смотреть.
Вы, видимо, просто не представляете сколько всего интересного за пределами Web.
Одними из основных направлений считаю - автоматизация (с элементами ИИ), data mining, и т.п.
И я бы на вашем месте еще бы сузил вопрос:

1. Какие именно из "web-приложений" вам не нравятся? Т.е. насколько широко Ваше понятие "приложение". Если же оно просто заканчивается на sharepoint, php, js и т.п., то, пожалуй скажу, что вы заблуждаетесь. Если больше, укажите пожалуйста хотя бы области, которые не нравятся.
2. Что вы называете интересными проектами? Больше конкретики... А то так гадать, куда же вам предложить пойти мы можем вечно.

**UPD1**
Насчет прикладных решений, вы ошибаетесь, никуда они не делись, просто остались невидимые "невооруженным" глазом направления. Для которых продукция, общепризнанных лидеров рынка, просто неприменима по каким-то причинам. И поверьте, платят там неплохо. Это в том числе узко специализированные прикладные проекты, которым просто не нужен веб. Вариантов масса, надо просто найти человека, который даст возможность развиться.

Я полагал, вы имели ввиду весь спектр веб-решений. В том числе работа с различными API. 
Например, работа с API какого-то банка, но ПО разрабатывается, например, под Андроид. С одной стороны это можно назвать веб-приложением, но с другой стороны это все же прикладуха для пользователя. Со стороны программиста это тоже больше прикладуха, имхо.

Возможно вам будут интересны разработки для новых течений в области хранения и обработки информации, например, такие как OLAP.

Одно, чего мне не хватало в процессе учебы, это чтобы кто-то показал, что есть на свете. Чтобы кто-то мог рассказать о новых технологиях, новых течениях и т.п. Поэтому я могу вас понять, до наших краев информация доходит весьма и весьма медленно. Не из чего выбрать, так как реально не знаешь из чего выбирать.

И еще, за границей особенной разницы между зарплатами прикладных программистов и веб-программистов не наблюдается (лично мое наблюдение из того, что видел/искал). Причина в том, что у нас з/п веб-программистов низки, а прикладных программистов еще ниже. имхо.

Comment: что есть что-то интересное я понимаю и очень даже представляю :) впринципе, я сейчас и так работаю там где мне интересно.. дело просто в том, что зарплата в перспективе много меньше чем у веб-разработчика..<br><br>
1. впринципе все) ни прикладные приколы типо приложения на страничке, ни сами по себе странички-порталы, ни sharepointы и иже с ними (хотя это же по сути те же порталы), ни верстка, ни скриптинг)

Comment: 2. те приложения, над которыми можно подумать :) я не отрицаю что думать-то оно везде надо, но на мой взгляд думать над тем, почему же сервис не отдает на страничку больше 8192х символов - это не интересно (пример надуман)..

Comment: Тогда придумайте свое приложение! Я осознал, что придумывая свое, можно неплохо заработать. Когда работаешь на "дядю", согласитесь, мало места для творчества. Хотите подумать, так думайте, действуйте!

Comment: см. UPD1

Comment: Отличный ответ и отличный совет - спасибо! :) Не ожидал такого рассуждения, если честно :) Я бы рад написать "своё", но тут дело не только программирования но и продажи.. На самом деле я сейчас работаю и получаю какую-то зарплату - просто думаю, есть ли вариант развиваться в ту сторону, где мне интересно, а не где больше спрос.. Надеюсь, Вы правы :)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант - desktop-клиент, работающий через web-сервисы

Comment: вариант чего? своего стартапа? :)

Comment: Когда речь идёт о своём стартапе, начинать надо с актуальной задачи, а не с решения.
Обычно при приёме на работу рассказывают, чем занимается компания.

Answer (score 2):

Насчет программирования может и да, на рынке софта образовались свои флагманы они обновляются свое ПО каждую неделю, месяц, конкурировать тяжело. И что же делать обычным кодерам ПО, они и идут в веб-разработку или к тем же флагманам присоединяются.
Ну если веб-разработка неинтересна, может разработка приложений или игр для смартфонов на андроиде была бы интересной, или для смартфонов с другими ОС; но по мне для андроида самое оно: он за считаные годы завоевал такую большую часть рынка смартов, тем более выходят каждую неделю новые тачфоны с супер характеристиками - это целый мир для творчества и идей.

Comment: я говорю не о том что бы писать свои программы с блекджеком и дальше по тексту - меня интересует, насколько велика вероятность сейчас устроиться на адекватную знаниям и опыту работу, не связанную с вебом? (адекватную - если сравнивать с аналогичными знаниями и опытом web-работу)

Answer (score 2):

Пишите на **.NET**, если web не нравится, да и если писать на .net, то при необходимости и под web можно спокойно писать.

Ну, а по факту, сейчас все движется к mobile-web, разные Pad'ы и Phone'ы стали популярными среди широкого круга людей, и поэтому разработка под них популярна и перспективна. А web сейчас выходит на уровень настольных программ, так что можно и тут расти, те же SaaS и PaaS, облака, SL, Flesh, ExtJS и т.д., могут творить чудеса.

Comment: Я и так пишу на .net - мне совершенно не нравится web разработка как таковая.. вопрос я уточню сейчас - видимо он не совсем точный.

Answer (score 2):

Про Web здесь писали уже выше, скажу о прикладном программировании: оно не умрет ни когда!Далеко не все завязано на вебе, начиная от микроконтроллеров и заканчивая робототехникой и ИИ (искуственный интеллект), разработки НАСА...

Comment: Не умрет-то оно не умерет, вопрос в другом (обновляю вопрос).

Answer (score 0):

Прикладное программирование не умирает, оно будет жить еще долго, однако технология действительно становиться ВЭБ. ВЭБ тоже прикладное программирование. Не понимаю что значит "скучно". Мое мнение (писал неоднократно на разных форумах уже), пора делать RIA приложения. Все плюсы налицо, кроссплатформенность, отсуствие необходимости инсталляции, легкое обновление, да и интерфейсы современные под ВЭБ уже обгоняют по юзабилитети классические приложение.
УЧИТЕ ВЭБ НЕ ПОЖАЛЕЕТЕ!

Comment: Если провести аналогию, то вот мне нравится копать(!) окопы и не нравится копать(!) могилы. И там, и сям, понятное дело, нужно копать, но могилы копать мне не нравится.

Comment: Ох и Оналогия(!). Я как человек принимающий решения какой софт покупать не покупаю последние 2 года не ВЭБ (конечно при условии что есть вэб решение). Нет покупателей нет денег нет ничего Капитализм. Дальше уж сами решайте ;-)

Comment: Покупатели есть всегда. А web - так и продают тут косвенно обычно (например, клики какие-нибудь, а не саму страницу). Меня немного пугает тенденция выводить проекты в облака (у нас в фирме это собираются сделать), но это всё таки остается приложением, а не становится сайтом.

Comment: Web хорош, конечно, но одна маленькая тонкость. Web-сервер и Web-браузер по сути своей не могут быть "Web-приложением", т.е. их ядро не может быть написано полностью на php и т.п.